# PHP, как сделать пагинацию таблицы?

Tags: php, pagination

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом можно сделать пагинацию таблицы? Она заполняется записями из БД, которые пополняются каждый день.

Comment: так же как и любую другую пагинацию. в чем именно вопрос?

Comment: @teran, я еще ни разу не делала пагинацию, вот и интересуюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень псевдокод, однако поможет понять суть:

```
// начальные данные
$count = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM таблица ; // общее кол-во записей
$itemPerPage = 10; // кол-во записей на страницу
$pagesCount = round($count / $itemPerPage); // кол-во страниц пагинации

// обработка запроса и формирование результатов
if($_GET['page']) {
    $from = $itemPerPage * $_GET['page'] - 1;
    $to = $itemPerPage * $_GET['page'];
    $результатs = SELECT что-то FROM таблица LIMIT $from, $to;
}else {
    $результатs = SELECT что-то FROM таблица LIMIT 0, $itemPerPage;
}

// выстраивание таблицы
foreach($результатs) {
    // выводим данные
}

// выстраивание пагинации
for( $i <= $pagesCount ) { // $i = 1
    <a href="&page=$i">$i</a> // $_GET['page']

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Но не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, объяснить что это за результатs и $_GET["page"]?

Comment: page это get-параметр, он передаётся при переходе по ссылке пагинации. Нажали на ссылку страницы в пагинации, страница перезагрузилась, проверилось условие if($_GET['page'])